# Converting between Endianness in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, byte, endianness

I have a value:

708877665544332211

And I'm creating a helper function in order to help me output:

0x1122334455667788

In my helper, I am able to access the last 8 bytes in the first value "8877665544332211". If anyone could provide me any sort of guidance on how to go about reversing the order, it would help me a lot! Thank you!

In my main function, to get the first number i have: in.d = * ((uint64_t* )(&mem[cpu.pc + 1])); 
where d is typedef uint64_t addr_t and mem is the memory array and cpu.pc is program counter

This reads in the last 8 bytes starting at the second byte because the total size is 9 bytes but the opcode is the first byte.

the 70 is just the opcode for y86 instructions.

in my helper, I have access to in.d and I am trying to figure out how to flip it in the helper.

Comment: If you have the *value*, endianness already depends on your machine. That said, what exactly are you asking?

Comment: So you're trying to output an 8byte number? What exactly are you trying to do? What problem are you having? What is your question?

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which shows your helper function and how it is used.

Comment: Use an `unsigned char *` to point to the number.  Then you can index each of the 8 bytes individually and move them around as needed.

Comment: So I'm trying to just output 1122334455667788 from this 8877665544332211. I'm just unsure on the logic of reversing the order of each byte

Comment: @dbush then you must know the endianness of the machine, which might or might not be what OP needs ... clarification would be good.

Comment: Google "byte swapping functions in C", and you might find _[something helpful](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/64797/byte-swapping-functions)_.  Or, if you really want to use your code, post it, and maybe someone can see where the problem is.

Comment: "from this 8877665544332211" - is "this" an integer, a string, or what? Please post a clear question.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Not necessarily.  If the value is in an unsigned 64-byte integer type, just swap the bytes and print it in hex format, and it should show up as swapped.

Comment: But it isn't: it has **70** in front, and the question remains unclear.

Comment: @dbush huh? if it's an `uint64_t` and you're on a little-endian machine, printing the bytes in their *stored order* will yield the desired result.

Comment: @FelixPalmen That's assuming you know you're little-endian.  Printing the value before and after swapping the bytes will reflect the swap regardless of endianness.

Comment: @dbush so you mean copying it to another unsigned integer type? Then you better make sure you don't have padding bits in your type (e.g. by using `uint64_t`).

Comment: added more clarification, let me know if anymore is needed @WeatherVane

Comment: @evak99 maybe I'm just being dumb, but I don't understand how 708877665544332211 can fit in a uint64_t, you seem to have 72 bits of data there.

Comment: i'm only accessing the last 8 bytes though because that's what i want to reverse so i'm storing that into a uint64_t. the first byte is just the opcode indicating what kind of instruction it is. the cpu.pc + 1 starts after the first byte and stores the last 8 bytes. @LukeSmith

Comment: @evak99 you still have not posted the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) requested earlier, so the question remians unclear.

Answer (score 1):

This function will switch the order of bytes in a uint64_t

```
uint64_t switch64(uint64_t i)
{
    uint64_t out = 
          ((i & (uint64_t)0xFF) << 56)
        | ((i & (uint64_t)0xFF00) << 40)
        | ((i & (uint64_t)0xFF0000) << 24)
        | ((i & (uint64_t)0xFF000000) << 8)
        | ((i & (uint64_t)0xFF00000000) >> 8)
        | ((i & (uint64_t)0xFF0000000000) >> 24)
        | ((i & (uint64_t)0xFF000000000000) >> 32) 
        | ((i & (uint64_t)0xFF00000000000000) >> 56);
    return out;
}
```

It can probably be done in fewer operations, but with this code it is clear what is going on.